# How to use application's resource from ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, templates

I get this error

> 'disable_glow' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'.

when trying to do this:

### Application's resources:

```
<LinearGradientBrush Opacity="0.0" StartPoint="0,0" 
  EndPoint="0,1" x:Key="disable_glow" x:Name="disable_glow">
    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#4D4D4D" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="#404040" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#2E2E2E" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

in here:

### Same place, in the ControlTemplate of the control Style:

```
<Border CornerRadius="4">
    <Border.Background>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource disable_glow}">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
...
```

When I use either StaticResource or DynamicResource keyword I get the same error.

So how to use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set the `x:Name` attribute on your LinearGradientBrush, if it's in a ResourceDictionary (i.e. a Resources collection). You just need to set `x:Key` to be able to access it.

The error you are getting would not be produced by the `Brush="{StaticResource disable_glow}"` code. If the resources wasn't found it would say something like "Resource not found". It sounds like you are/were trying to access it by name.

You would need to ensure that your LinearGradientBrush is defined before your ControlTemplate.

Comment: It **is** defined before at least because it is located above all the brush usage and brush's container the Style and ControlTemplate and everything.

Comment: @AgentFire - Are there any of occurances of "disable_glow" in your project? As I said, StaticResource would not produce that type of error.

Comment: @AgentFire - Sorry, meant - Are there any *other* occurrences of "disable_glow"...

Comment: There is only links of using of this resource. There is no other `x:name="disable_glow"` resources neither in the usable area nor any other place in the entire app. Also, there is a storyboards in the App Resources that use the "disable_glow" as a TargetName. In turn, the SBoards also are used in the ControlTemplate, in triggers section.

Comment: @AgentFire - Then that's most likely your problem. I don't believe you can reference resources by name in Storyboards like that. The Brush would have to be defined in the ControlTemplate/Style in order to use TargetName to reference it.

Comment: The thing is, in CnotrolTemplate.Resources it works. In app ones it does not.

Comment: @AgentFire - That would make sense as the ControlTemplate is it's own "name scope". Anything outside of it would not be accessible by name.

Comment: Why then I can access the outside resources such as `SolidBrush`es? A simple brush is fully accessable whereas the `Storyboard`s' through `LinearGradientBrush` returns an error.

Comment: @AgentFire - Just to be clear, let's make a distinction. Using StaticResource/DynamicResource is different than using the TargetName of a Storyboard. If you remove your story boards, then you should be able to access any type of brush defined before your ControlTemplate using StaticResource/DynamicResource. Using TargetName, you should only be able to access brushes defined inside your ControlTemplate. Are you seeing something different than that?